# Webstorm - how to disable 'dfn' shourtcut?

Tags: webstorm

I want to set my live template for css like

```
df
```

After this I want to be displayed:

```
display: flex;
```

But in my Webstorm I have some predefined shourtcut and I cannot find any clues how to disable it in LiveTemplates. It's really annoying to always press bottom arrow when I want to write display: flex;

[image]

Comment: Are you editing CSS in *.css* or *.js* file?

Comment: in .vue file but it also works in .scss

Comment: Try making your own Live Template where `df` will be used as an abbreviation. Since it's an exact match it will have priority over `dfn` or `d:f` entries.

Comment: As you can see in the image above I did this and still dfn is more important than mine

Comment: @Freestyle09 I do not see an entry with `df` abbreviation there. FYI: `d:f` is not the same as `df`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDE suggests existing HTML elements in completion; `dfn` is the [Definition element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn); there is no way to remove it from completion list